# react-native-background-timer errors on Expo development build

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to use react-native-background-timer. It's clear from their docs that you can't use it in a managed workflow and have to "eject" your app to a bare workflow.

I'm still very unclear on the concept of the managed and bare workflows and the idea of ejecting your app, as there's tons of conflicting info online. In the Expo docs, they say that "ejecting" your app is now deprecated in favor of "development builds", and that you should be able to add non-Expo modules into your project by just running the builds for iOS and Android separately. I guess somehow this is supposed to compile the platform-specific code for you, and you get an "Expo Go"-like wrapped version of your app that has all that stuff embedded, but still allows you to develop using JS code on top of that? I don't know, no one explains it clearly.

I've tried adding the react-native-background-timer module to my app and building the Android version using `npx expo run:android`. Unfortunately it fails immediately with various errors such as `new NativeEventEmitter() was called with a non-null argument without the required addListener method` and `TypeError: Cannot set property 'NaN' of undefined, js engine: hermes`. I'm guessing these are errors due to managed vs bare thing but not sure.

I also did try following the react-native-background-timer instructions for manually linking on Android and that did not help either -- it gave me a duplicate module error.

If "ejecting" is deprecated, how am I supposed to use react-native-background-timer? How do you run these platform-specific modules in an Expo react-native app? Thanks in advance for the help.